# Unable to convert DateTime timestamp to m/d/y format

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

So I am using an API and I am getting the following `updatedOn` response: `"UpdatedOn": "/Date(1674542180860+0000)/"`.

I am using the following code to convert it to `m/d/y` format:

```
if (!empty($data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn)): 
    $timestamp = preg_replace('/[^0-9+-]/', '', $data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn);
    $date = new DateTime("@$timestamp");
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $parse_date = date('m/d/Y', $timestamp);
    echo '<span>' . $parse_date . '</span>';
endif;
```

The issue is that it's not outputting properly, so I need some help - Here is the output that I am receiving:

`02/17/55034`

I would like to output it in the following format: `January 12th, 2023`.

Could anyone help me with my code?

Comment: There are +2 issues here. `$data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn` equals `Date(1674542180860+0000)` or something else?

Comment: You are sure `January 12th, 2023` is correct? Seems like Jan 24 2023 is correct and this is an epoch timestamp in micro format so dividing by 1000 resolves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our decade timestamp is a 10 digit number
So this nember => "1674542180860" must be devide to 1000,
And if these two numbers "1674542180860" and "0000" must be added together, we should explod this string and sum two number,
I suggest you try this:

```
if (!empty($data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn)){
            $timestamp = preg_replace('/[^0-9+-]/', '', $data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn);
            $timestamp = explode('+',$timestamp);
            $timestamp = (int)$timestamp[0] + (int)$timestamp[1];
            $timestamp = (int)($timestamp/1000);
            $parse_date = date('F d\t\h Y', $timestamp);
            echo '<span>' . $parse_date . '</span>';
        }
```

This is your favorite format to show date => "F d\t\h Y"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn)){
    $parse_date = date('M d, Y', strtotime($data->Data->Shipment->UpdatedOn));
    echo '<span>' . $parse_date . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.